# docker bridge can't reach external address defined as `route via`

Tags: networking, bridge, iproute, docker-compose

I have 3 raspberry pi in a *daisy-chain* network, with `ip route`s and `iptables accept fwd` - all three hosts can reach each others:

```
    A <--> B <--> C
```

However a container from docker-compose running with default bridge network driver on **A**, cannot reach **C**.

Pi A (10.58.3.1):

- `ip route add 10.76.5.0/24 via 10.58.3.3`
- has docker-compose with default bridge network driver

Pi B (10.58.3.3 and 10.76.5.1):

- `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT`

Pi C (10.76.5.5):

- `ip route add 10.58.3.0/24 via 10.76.5.1`

Tried **nexthop** with both the bridge (172.22.0.1) and container IPs (172.22.0.4), eg: `ip route add 10.76.5.0/24 nexthop via 10.58.3.3 nexthop via 172.22.0.1` but get `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Tried defining bridge in docker-compose with option `com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0"` but can't find any clear documentation here so am lost.

How can I reach **C** from the container running on **A**?

Comment: Would you update your question to include the output of the `ip route` command on hostA, hostB, and hostC, and also in the container? The configuration you've described here should "just work" with only the two `ip route` commands you show for hostA and hostC, respectively.

Comment: @larsks  thank you for asserting that this should "just work" - helped me narrow down the problem in minutes rather than the hours already lost googling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was between the chair and keyboard and had fat fingers

Days ago I'd hacked around with the configuration file for container app and rewired some paths incorrectly.  Only noticed I hadn't reverted when capturing additional info re: @lasks comment.